# Empty latex tables list

Tags: latex, overleaf

i'm trying to make a list of tables in latex

```
        \listoffigures
        \thispagestyle{frontmatter}
        \listoftables
        \thispagestyle{frontmatter}
```

the list of tables is displayed empty meanwhile there are tables in the document

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Did you check that there are no errors in your document? An error would prevent latex from compiling your document the necessary number of times to show the LoT